# Copy excel sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excels "A" and "B".

A has three sheets "1", "2", "3".
B has two sheets "1", "2"

If I want to copy "3" to excel B but i want VBA to compare the sheet names in excel A and B and then find the missing sheet in B ie "3" and copy it

Comment: Can you show us what you tried for your own? Even if copying some code from internet...

Comment: actually, have not tried much. new to VBA so still learning.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("2").Copy After:=Workbooks("B.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("B.xlsm").Sheets.Count)
```

To explain what it does:
This part is pretty obvious, it takes the Sheet called "2" from the workbook "A" :

```
Workbooks("A.xlsm").Sheets("2").Copy
```

This part pastes the sheet "2" into Workbook "B", directly after its last existing sheet

```
After:=Workbooks("B.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("B.xlsm").Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: could you help me with the edited question